# Not using % or any java built in methods (math), how to do modulo exponentiation?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures, modulo

So I need to do modulo exponentiation using 2^N mod M, but I cant use % or any built in java.math or Math method. Applying mod M as 2^N increases seems* like it would work. But is doesn't seem to ( or im just doing it wrong...)

```
int N = 63;
int M = 1000;
int result;
while (n > 0)
    {
        power *= 2;
        n --;   
        // this part defn doesnt work... best idea so far 
        if (power >M)
        {
            result = power - m; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What do you need to exponent, a given number or 1? Where is `power` declaration?

Comment: Let me clear it up (sorry bout that mate) 2^N mod M

Comment: Why can't you use `%`?

Comment: Besides the bug, you can justify the method as follows: 1] (2.X) mod M = (2.(X mod M)) mod M; more generally (2^N) mod M = (2.(2.(2.(2.(... 2 mod M ...) mod M) mod M) mod M) mod M; 2] if p = X mod M, then 0 <= p < M so that 0 <= 2.p < 2.M; then either 0 <= 2.p < M or M <= 2.p < 2.M; in the latter case, by subtracting M, p' = p - M,  you obtain 0 <= p' < M; in both cases this gives you (2.p) mod M.

Comment: Haven't you noticed that it is the power of ***2***? Why hadn't you used it? Make power by shift.

Comment: @Gangnus: * 2 or << 1 will make no difference, both taking a single clock. The challenge is the modulo, not the power.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But you needn't do it by cycles of <<1, make <<N once. 2^63 is still long number in Java. My answer is greatly shorter and simpler than this prog.

Comment: And obviously, if the base of power is 2, the teacher WANTED the students to use <<.

Comment: @Gangnus: yep, but it uses integer division, virtually the same as modulo. The teacher forgot to explicitly rule it out. Or he could have stated "N up to 1000".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why? May be, he want the students to use the base  integer arithmetics. I HAD given my students such tasks 27 years ago.

Comment: @Gangnus: My reasoning is the following: if the exercise was about the relation between % and /, there was no reason for the first argument to be a power of 2; if the exercise was about the powers of 2 using shifts, there was no reason to take the modulo. Anyway, the choice N=63 is intriguing: the exercise gets more interesting when it makes you pass the overflow barrier.

Comment: But the very choice of 2^63 should remind of long range. And the very choice of base 2 should remind of shift. And while we don't use cycles, we have to count module without them. So, /,*,- variant is intermittent.

Comment: @Gangnus: sorry, I completely miss the meaning of this sentence: "And while we don't use cycles, we have to count module without them", and of this one: "So, /,*,- variant is intermittent".

Comment: In the given example of code there is a cycle that counts both power and module - simultaneously. As there are no cycles for power, we can't use them for module. "/,*,-" - is the sequence of arithmetic operators you need to count module in an easy way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [§15.17.3 "Remainder Operator %" of *The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), `(a/b)*b+(a%b)` is always equal to `a`. Turning this around, we have `a%b == a - (a/b)*b`. So, you should be able to write:

```
power *= 2;
power -= (power/M) * M;
```

Or, since you're only multiplying by two each time, you know that `power` cannot exceed `M` before this operation, so you can rewrite the above as:

```
power *= 2;
if (power > M) {
    power -= M;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the best answers in a while. A +1 well earned for the above explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `power -= m` instead of `result = power - m`?

Answer (score 1):

Since [`BigInteger.modPow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) already implements this, you should just look at [the source code of `BigInteger`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html).

Comment: Instructive, but the implementation uses a modulo operator. Very close to the efficient solution of @Silviu Burcea.

Answer (score 1):

Annotated code:

```
    int M = 13;
    int result = 2;
    int n = 10;

    while (--n > 0) // do n iterations multiplying the number with 2
        result *= 2;

    if (M < 0) // safe guard if someone gives you a negative M then flip it
        M *= -1;

    while ((result-M) >= 0) // keep subtracting M until right before it turns negative
        result -= M;
```

Remember though, that integers are not big enough for 2^63 like your code shows you're trying to do. ints are 32 bit signed, so 2^31 to -2^31-1 is the range.

Your version seems also to do modulus on each iteration of multiplication. You can do that, too. And it will allow you to use 2^63 like your code tries:

```
    int M = 13;
    int result = 2;
    int n = 10;

    if (M < 0)
        M *= -1;

    while (--n > 0) {
        result *= 2;
        while ((result-M) >= 0)
            result -= M;
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong, result will overflow for big enough n. Also, if M = Integer.MIN_VALUE, your safeguard is futile. I don't usually down vote, but I feel you deserve it.

Comment: I added a non-overflowing version. I wont edit for M = MIN_VALUE though. The safeguard is not "futile". It aligns the results with java's modulus operator for negative dividers.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: power and modulo > 0, a validation should be in place before calling this method.

```
long modPow(long x, long power, long modulo) {
  if (power > 1) {
    x = modPow(x, power / 2, modulo) * modPow(x, (power + 1) / 2, modulo);
  }
  return x - x / modulo * modulo;
}
```

call it:

```
result = modPow(2, power, modulo);
```

Here is a recursive version. If power is too big to handle it, we split it in 2. We then return x % modulo(inspired by ["ruakh example"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21521971/1051677)). We also know that:

```
y = y / 2 + (y + 1) / 2
```

so

```
x^n = x^(n/2) * x^[(n+1)/2]
```

This way, we know that every modPow call will return a number smaller than modulo every time.

Advantages? Parallelization and if you want to make things even fancier, add memoisation.

You can easily convert my version in a Fork / Join model, you can find more details about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `power-=M` as the modulo is nothing but continuous subtraction of the divisor from divident until the `divident<divisor`.

The below should work

```
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String []args){
int N = 63;
int M = 1000;
long result=0;
long power=1;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        power *= 2;
        N--; 
       if (power >=M)
        {
            power = power - M; 
        }

    }
    System.out.println("power:"+power);
     }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this code was wrong from the beginning. The `if` condition should be `power >= M` (i.e. the negation of remainder<divisor) otherwise you could end up with `power == M`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you noticed that it is the power of ***2*** ? Why hadn't you used it?

2^N mod M is to be counted as

```
long power=1L << N;
long temp=power/M;
long result= power-temp*M;
```

Comment: One *word*: overflow.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea 2^63 is a normal long. No overflow here.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea according to the code with the N and M set, this is the only test case to be checked. And if we take that no limitations exist at all, then your variant doesn't work, too, with M and N out of int range.

Comment: I know there are some limitations for some extreme cases, I have some ideas but I think they are way out of question scope. Anyway, I like that you used bit-shift :)

Comment: I assume that by `2L << N` you meant `1L << N`. Notice that Java longs are signed so that they represent all integers in range `-2^63 to +2^63-1`. Few languages support unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust anyway, the questioner is not interested in the subject anymore, it seems.